# mysql replication incompatible statements problem

Tags: mysql, replication, compatibility, master-slave

i wanted to setup a new mysql database slave running a newer version of mysql => 5.1.41 than the master => 5.0.75, which -- as far as i know -- should normally be no problem. however, as it turns out setting up replication fails, because i used a SQL statement in 5.0.75 which apparently does not work in 5.1.41 anylonger:

the statement which causes the trouble looks like:

```
DELETE FROM tab1 t1
USING       tab1 t1, tab2 t2
WHERE       t2.field1 = ...
AND         t2.field2 = ...
AND         t1.field1 = t2.field2;
```

this statements runs perfectly on 5.0.75, on 5.1.41 i get the following error message in my slave status:

```
...
Last_SQL_Errno: 1064
Last_SQL_Error: Error 'You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that      
                corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to 
                use near 't1
                USING       tab1 t1, tab2 t2
                ...
...
```

any ideas, what's going on and what to do?

thanks!

**UPDATE**

ok, i solved this problem by compiling 5.0.75 on the slave myself ... however, i would still be interested, what's going on and how to deal with such problems. thanks.

Comment: sorry -- please vote to move over to serverfault. apparently i have too many open browser-tabs and posted in the wrong one :-(. it's sometimes really hard to keep the overview over all those same-looking qa sites ...

Answer (score -1):

For errors like this (that aren't important) you can filter out in the my.ini file.

```
# skip replication errors
slave-skip-errors=1062,1136,1146
```

Or alternatively modify the offending code so that it is version friendly.